# aws ec2 instance, security groups creation logs from terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, terraform

What is the best place to save the logs of AWS ec2 instance creation, secuirty groups, role creation logs?
I am thinking of saving them in S3 on a seperate bucket, but I was wondering if there any good articles on logging strategies.
thnaks
Nate

Comment: Do you mean like [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/)? It stores logs in S4 buckets.

Comment: You have Aws cloud trail or aws config and you also can save the output plan from terraform as well.